# UITabBarController animated transition between views

Tags: swift, xcode

I set custom class for tabbarcontroller with redefined func tabBarController, but it doesn't fire when i click tabbar item.
Full project here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vKmruj6yzCHv6bxw6tiRcftqN-UuAp4i

```
     import UIKit

    class UITabBarControllerAnimated: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self as? UITabBarControllerDelegate
        print("start")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        if selectedViewController == nil || viewController == selectedViewController {
            print("nop")
            return false
        }

        let fromView = selectedViewController!.view
        let toView = viewController.view

        UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 0.8, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)
        print( "animation go")
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code the problem is you implement

```
self.delegate = self as? UITabBarControllerDelegate
```

it unable to conform UITabBarController to UITabBarControllerDelegate,
please make some changes

```
class UITabBarControllerAnimated: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    print("start")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

it's working fine